# Can't install other linux distros except ubuntu

Tags: linux, debian, fedora

I got a dell g5 5505 (ryzen 5 and amd Radeon graphics) I tried to try out a live img of debian 10.8 , but it ends up in a black screen. So I tried linux mint (black screen) , fedora 33 (freezes) , but ubuntu 20.04 works fine. How could I install other linux distribution??

Comment: Unfortunately, this can be a challenge depending on the distro, and your hardware. I've found that in general, 3-5 year-old Intel-based desktops and Ubuntu are the easiest. Another variable is the user community - some are helpful (Mint is wonderful IMHO), some not so much (Arch). If your PC uses [EFI](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+efi&t=ffnt&ia=web), you may find that [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is very useful. Be patient, read a lot, ask questions in a forum focused on the distro you're trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 33 must absolutely work as it contains one the latest and greatest kernels. Please try using the latest netinstall image (don't mind the "server" word on the page - the netinstall image can be used to install any Fedora configuration): https://getfedora.org/en/server/download/

If it fails to boot/freezes you must absolutely try to debug the issue and file a bug report because by doing so you'll eliminate the bug and help other Linux users: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Also, you should not think of Linux distros as independent operating systems, they are not.

- All Linux distros are compiled from the same sources, sometimes patched, sometimes without any patches
- Distros depending on their package policy may include different versions of packages or stick to some old versions to preserve API/ABI/behavior (RHEL and derivatives, Debian, Ubuntu LTS)
- Distros and how they boot is all about the Linux kernel version and firmware included by them - so, what you're observing is most likely down to either a particular kernel release or a presence/absence of the required firmware.

It all looks a little bit complicated, almost like a mess, and it unfortunately is.

Comment: Options to try while booting Linux distros: `nomodeset`, also try removing `quiet` and anything which looks like a graphical boot.